# multi-friend-selector action does not break out of iframe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

we have a facebook app and every time a user invites a friend the application redirects to the "action" URL but it's always facebook inside of an iframe.  For the life of me I've tried every combination of URL's for the action, but it just won't break out of the frame.

Any idea how to avoid this?

Thanks,
Chad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem resided inside our usage of the mini_fb library.  works now.  nice library.